# Modify text length OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a paragraph which is limited in length. When the limit is reached, a "**+**" sign is added at the end of the shortened text.

I would like to make this "**+**" **clickable** so the rest of the paragraph will appear. Then by clicking on the paragraph, the text should shorten again.

Example:

[image]

By now I could just manage to limit the text size and add a "+" at the end.

Code:

```js
var myDiv = $('#trim');
var myDivlength = myDiv.text().length;

if(myDivlength>10){
    myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,10));
    myDiv.append(" ..." + '+');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


  <p id="trim">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>




</body>
```

Comment: Your code is throwing away anything after 10 characters, so how do you propose to get it back?

Comment: Instead of truncating the text, you could just create a fixed-width div and put it in that. Then, when clicking the + you could expand the div. OR You could just load the additional text via ajax, replacing the truncated text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve all of the required behaviour with CSS using `no-wrap`, `text-overflow` and a `:after` pseudo element for the `+` character. You then simply need to toggle the class in the JS `click` handler. Try this:

```js
$('#trim').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('full');
});
```

```css
#trim {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#trim:after {
  content: '+';
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#trim.full {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
#trim.full:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p id="trim">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
```

Comment: Thx you for your help, the behaviour is really great. Just one thing: would it give a way to have no '+' sign displayed when the text width is smaller than the 400px defined in #trim?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use css for this with a fixed width and the following attributes:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

You can then have something like this in your css

```
 .mytext {
     width: 200px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }

 .mytext.expanded {
     overflow: visible
 }
```

have this piece of html in your template

```
  <p id="trim" class="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p> <div id='expand'>+</div>
```

and in the js :

```
$('#expand').click(function({
    $('#trim').toggleClass('expanded');
}));
```

Comment: Note that for `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work the element has to have a fixed size.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id='more'>+</div>
```

```js
$('#more').click(function({
    $('#trim').text();
}));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting this to do, but I am sure it doesn't do it.

Comment: All this does is use the getter of the `text()` method without actually assigning it to anything

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: This is not valid code. You are passing an object literal where the parser expects parameter names. You have a misplaced parenthesis, and you are just getting the text and doing nothing with it.